# I am trying to pass values into dateTime object but there is a problem when month it's less than month10

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass into datatime object, the day, month and year but there is a problem with the month to print when the value is less than month 10. 
In my code, I have a inicial date and with arithmetic, I calculate the clean month and the notification month. Also I do what have to happen if the last day of the month is 30 or 31 and especific case with month 2.

here is my code:

```
    int day = (int)DateTime.Now.Day;
    int month = (int)DateTime.Now.Month;
    int year = (int)DateTime.Now.Year;

    int diaLimpeza, mesLimpeza, anoLimpeza;
    int diaNotifica, mesNotifica, anoNotifica;

  public void mes6()
    {
        DateTime dataInicial = new DateTime();
        DateTime dataLimpeza = new DateTime();
        DateTime dataNotifica = new DateTime();

        day = 31;
        month = 12;
        year = 2019;

        mesLimpeza=  month + 6;
        if (mesLimpeza > 12)
        {
            mesLimpeza = mesLimpeza - 12;
            anoLimpeza = year + 1;
            diaLimpeza = day;

        }
        else
        {
            mesLimpeza = month + 6;
            anoLimpeza = year;
            diaLimpeza = day;
        }

        int soma = diaLimpeza + 2;

        diaNotifica = soma;

        if (mesLimpeza == 01 || mesLimpeza == 03 || mesLimpeza == 05 || mesLimpeza == 07 || mesLimpeza == 08 || mesLimpeza == 10) //mesLimpeza == 12 excepçao
        {
            if (diaLimpeza == 30 || diaLimpeza == 31)
            {
                diaNotifica = diaNotifica - 31;
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                //int a = diaNotifica;
            }

            else if ((diaLimpeza == 30 || diaLimpeza == 31) && mesLimpeza == 12)
            {
                diaNotifica = diaNotifica - 31;
                mesNotifica = (mesLimpeza + 1) - 12;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                diaNotifica = diaLimpeza + 2;
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
            }
        }
        else if (mesLimpeza == 04 || mesLimpeza == 06 || mesLimpeza == 09 || mesLimpeza == 11)
        {
            if (diaLimpeza == 29 || diaLimpeza == 30)
            {
                diaNotifica = diaLimpeza - 30;
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
            }
            else
            {
                diaNotifica = diaLimpeza + 2;
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
            }
        }
        else if (mesLimpeza == 02)
        {
            if (anoLimpeza % 4 == 0)
            {
                if (diaLimpeza == 28 || diaLimpeza == 29)
                {
                    diaNotifica = diaLimpeza - 29;
                    mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                    anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (diaLimpeza == 27 || diaLimpeza == 28)
                {
                    diaNotifica = diaLimpeza - 28;
                    mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                    anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                }
                else
                {
                    diaNotifica = diaLimpeza + 2;
                    mesNotifica = mesLimpeza;
                    anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                }
            }
        }

        dataLimpeza = new DateTime(anoLimpeza, mesLimpeza, diaLimpeza);

        textBoxData.Text = dataLimpeza.ToShortDateString();

    }
```

In the last row, I'am trying to show in textBox the format of the date like (yyyy-MM-dd).

I had simulate given a inicial day, month and year and everything is fine, when the result of the month is iqual or more than 10.

When the value is less, I get this error on the image:

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDNeJ.png)

I had noted that the month format don't acept the number less than 10 without Zero like month "6" and I have to put "06" to make it right format.

How can I solve this problem?

I am using C# in visual studio.

Comment: An ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the arguments passed to the method is not null and contains an invalid value that is not a member of the set of values expected for the argument. [Please see more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.2). If you set a breakpoint on `dataLimpeze` and step, what is this value?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do in this code. Could you explain the business purpose of it more clearly? Chances are you should be able to do it with *much* less code than this.

Comment: the value of the breakpoint in dataLimpeza is +  dataLimpeza {01/01/0001 00:00:00} System.DateTime

Comment: I try to print into textbox the dataformat like I had Explain before

Comment: If your code is just trying to add 6 months, you can use `DateTime.AddMonths(6)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your final date is invalid, you are creating a date with month = 6(June) and date = 31.
but June does not have a day 31. I have added one line of code

`if (diaLimpeza > 30)
diaLimpeza--;`

after `else if (mesLimpeza == 04 || mesLimpeza == 06 || mesLimpeza == 09 || mesLimpeza == 11)` to minus one day.

[image]

Comment: `If the diaLimpeza  >30 ` it means that you past to another month that's why I 
subtract 30 days after the addition

Comment: @Joelson26 then increase the month value by one? June do not have day 31. Which line you did that? That line is not executed because you check month value first, Debug your code you will find.

Comment: Look here at this part of the code:

`else if (mesLimpeza == 04 || mesLimpeza == 06 || mesLimpeza == 09 || mesLimpeza == 11)
       {
          if (diaLimpeza == 29 || diaLimpeza == 30)
                {
                    diaNotifica = diaLimpeza - 30;
                    mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                    anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                }
                else
                {
                    diaNotifica = diaLimpeza + 2;
                    mesNotifica = mesLimpeza;
                    anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                }
            }`

Comment: Let me explain better. IF we are in June, the last day is 30. my day of notification increase for 32. As June doesn't have 32 days, I make 32-30 = 2. this 2 is the day for the next month not in the June. I debuged now and I saw this.

Comment: `mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1` you did this but in the last line `dataLimpeza = new DateTime(anoLimpeza, mesLimpeza, diaLimpeza);` you did not pass `mesNotifica`. you pass `mesLimpeza` which value is still 6.

Comment: is correct. I want the `mesLimpeza` that is 6, but I get this error because I have '6' and I pretend to have '06' with zero

Comment: If you substitute the `DateTime(anoLimpeza, mesLimpeza, diaLimpeza)` with `DateTime("2019-04-09")` you will see that works but yoy take off the zero of the month, you'll get error. that's the error I want to solve

Comment: @Joelson26 no 6 is fine, you need to increase the value of `mesLimpeza` because  you are creating a date object by `dataLimpeza = new DateTime(anoLimpeza, mesLimpeza, diaLimpeza);`. and the mesLimpeza = 6  and diaLimpeza = 31.

Comment: give me some test cases: value of day = 31;         month = 12;         year = 2019; and your desire date as output I can test.

Comment: imagine day = 31; month = 12; year = 2019 . I have to add mor 6 months to for the my dateLimpeza and mor 2 days in dateLimpeza. In this case I have to have

`inicialDate(31,12,2019)` `dateLimpeza(30,06,2020)` `dateNotifica(2,07,2020)`

Now I saw the error. the last day of June is not 31 but 30 @Hasam Mahmood

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing things the hard way:

```
textBoxData.Text = (new DateTime(year, month, day).AddMonths(6).AddDays(2)).ToShortDateString();
```

should do the trick.

Let the objects do the date arithmetic for you.

Comment: I will try your solution too.

Comment: Thank you all for the Help. You make me see what was wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, when user choose 6 months in combobox, I calculate de beginner date, the clean date and notification date. also I see if the year is a Leap year. Be careful in month 02 in the test. if is not a leap Year and you test with day 29, you 'll get a error because day 29 doesn't exist im february when year is a leap year.

```
    int day = (int)DateTime.Now.Day;
    int month = (int)DateTime.Now.Month;
    int year = (int)DateTime.Now.Year;

    int diaLimpeza, mesLimpeza, anoLimpeza,diaNotifica, mesNotifica, anoNotifica;

  public void mes6()
  {
        DateTime dataInicial = new DateTime();
        DateTime dataLimpeza = new DateTime();
        DateTime dataNotifica = new DateTime();

        day = 28;
        month = 02;
        year = 2018;

        mesLimpeza=  month + 6;
        if (mesLimpeza > 12)
        {
            mesLimpeza = mesLimpeza - 12;
            anoLimpeza = year + 1;
            diaLimpeza = day;

        }
        else
        {
            mesLimpeza = month + 6;
            anoLimpeza = year;
            diaLimpeza = day;
        }

        if (mesLimpeza == 01 || mesLimpeza == 03 || mesLimpeza == 05 || mesLimpeza == 07 || mesLimpeza == 08 || mesLimpeza == 10 || mesLimpeza == 12) //mesLimpeza == 12 excepçao
        {
            if (diaLimpeza == 30 || diaLimpeza == 31)
            {
                diaNotifica = (diaLimpeza + 2) - 31;
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
            }

            else if ((diaLimpeza == 30 || diaLimpeza == 31) && mesLimpeza == 12)
            {
                diaNotifica = (diaLimpeza + 2)-31;
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                diaNotifica = diaLimpeza + 2;
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
            }
        }
        else if (mesLimpeza == 04 || mesLimpeza == 06 || mesLimpeza == 09 || mesLimpeza == 11)
        {
            if (diaLimpeza > 30)
            {
                diaLimpeza = 30;
            }
            if (diaLimpeza == 29 || diaLimpeza == 30)
            {
                diaNotifica = (diaLimpeza + 2) - 30; //mudei esta linha
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
            }
            else
            {
                diaNotifica = diaLimpeza + 2;
                mesNotifica = mesLimpeza;
                anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
            }
        }
        else if (mesLimpeza == 02)
        {
            if (anoLimpeza % 4 == 0)
            {
                if (diaLimpeza == 30 || diaLimpeza == 31)
                {
                    diaLimpeza = 29;

                    if (diaLimpeza == 28 || diaLimpeza == 29)
                    {
                        diaNotifica = (diaLimpeza + 2) - 29;
                        mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                        anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                    }
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                if (diaLimpeza >= 28 && diaLimpeza <= 31)
                {
                    diaLimpeza = 28;

                    if (diaLimpeza == 27 || diaLimpeza == 28)
                    {
                        diaNotifica = (diaLimpeza + 2) - 28;
                        mesNotifica = mesLimpeza + 1;
                        anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    diaNotifica = diaLimpeza + 2;
                    mesNotifica = mesLimpeza;
                    anoNotifica = anoLimpeza;
                }
            }
        }
        dataInicial = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        dataLimpeza = new DateTime(anoLimpeza,mesLimpeza, diaLimpeza);
        dataNotifica = new DateTime(anoNotifica, mesNotifica, diaNotifica);

        textBoxData.Text = dataInicial.ToShortDateString() + "\r\n" + dataLimpeza.ToShortDateString() + "\r\n" + dataNotifica.ToShortDateString();

    }

 private void guardaStock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboLimpeza.Text == "6 Meses")
        {
            mes6();
        }
    }
```